# How to integrate it?

Tags: integration

I've got a problem with this integral.
How to calculate it?
$$
\int\frac{2^x}{\sqrt{1-4^x}} \, dx
$$

Regards.

Comment: Hint: $4^x = (2^x)^2$.

Comment: You may use the [IntTutor](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=Student/Calculus1/IntTutor) command of Maple to this end. The one shows [a solution step by step](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=examples/Calculus1SingleStepping) with explanations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a hint:
$$
\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4^x}}\Big(2^x\,dx\Big)
$$
In other words, you want a substitution in which $2^x\,dx$ becomes either $du$ or some constant times $du$.  That's the sort of thing you want to look for.

That's the hint.  Below are the details.

\begin{align}
u & = 2^x \\[10pt]
u^2 & = 4^x \\[10pt]
du & = 2^x(\log_e 2)\,dx
\end{align}
So
$$
\int\frac{2^x}{\sqrt{1-4^x}}\, dx = \frac{1}{\log_e2} \int \frac{du}{\sqrt{1-u^2}} =\frac{1}{\log_e 2}\arcsin(u)+C
$$
$$
=\frac{1}{\log_e 2}\arcsin(2^x)+C.
$$

Comment: Nice and clear answer, but "hint"?! :P

Comment: The first paragraph is the hint; the rest is the rest.  (I've edited the answer to make that explicit.)

Answer (score 1):

Let $2^x=u\implies 2^x \ln2 dx=du$

$$\int\frac{2^xdx}{\sqrt{1-4^x}}=\frac1{\ln2}\int\frac{du}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}=\frac{\arcsin u}{\ln2}+K=\frac{\arcsin (2^x)}{\ln2}+K $$ where $K$ is arbitrary constant of indefinite integration